# Reading from Redshift into Spark Dataframe (Spark-Redshift Module)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I'm following along the spark-redshift tutorial to read from redshift into spark (databricks). I have the following code:

```
val tempDir = "s3n://{my-s3-bucket-here}"



val jdbcUsername = "usernameExample"
val jdbcPassword = "samplePassword"
val jdbcHostname = "redshift.companyname.xyz"
val jdbcPort = 9293
val jdbcDatabase = "database"
val jdbcUrl = "sampleURL"


sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "SAMPLEAWSKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "SECRETKEYHERE")

val subs_dim = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").option("url", jdbcUrl).option("tempdir", tempDir).option("dbtable", "example.exampledb").load()
```

Now, when I attempt to run this, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: You must specify a method for authenticating Redshift's connection to S3 (aws_iam_role, forward_spark_s3_credentials, or temporary_aws_*. For a discussion of the differences between these options, please see the README.
```

I'm a bit confused, as I have defined the awsAccesskeyID using sc.hadoopConfiguration.set. I'm new at my company so I'm wondering if the AWS key is wrong, or if I'm missing something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the README? Did it shed any light?

Comment: Yeah I checked it out, it said to set the AWS credentials...which I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only reason I see, it is not passing the S3 credentials to Redshift connection as you have not setup `forward_spark_s3_credentials`.

Add below option to your call.

```
option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true");
```

Refer below [documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) snippet.

> Forward Spark's S3 credentials to Redshift: if the forward_spark_s3_credentials option is set to true then this library will automatically discover the credentials that Spark is using to connect to S3 and will forward those credentials to Redshift over JDBC.

Hope it help you!